# how to evaluate the javascript code in php when the js function is called?

Tags: javascript, php

iam trying to execute a script which evaluates some php before calling the javascript function but how to evaluate $('#routeid').val() in the url when the javascript function is called?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('transportation/vehiclecapacity',array('id'=>"$('#routeid').val()")); ?>",
```

Comment: You might have mixed up the evaluation order - I assume your PHP interpreter first parses above code and replaces the `<?php ...?>` part with the result of `echo ...`. Then, this file is served to the client browser and the JavaScript is finally executed.

Comment: sorry that what i meant, but how after the echo to get $('#routeid').val() evaluated by javascript again so that i have a complete url, as the above is not evaluated

Comment: Simple string concatenation ...

Comment: does this ajax call fired on any event?

Comment: yes on dropbox change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two solutions:

1) php can't just executed after calling some js-function. You should send AJAX request for retrieve url and then use it in your AJAX request.

2) (I think this point better) You can generate on php url with some token:

```
<?php echo $this->createUrl('transportation/vehiclecapacity',array('id'=>"str_to_replace")); ?>
```

and then on js you can replace part of url with which you like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('transportation/vehiclecapacity',array('id'=>'str_to_replace')); ?>".replace("str_to_replace", $('#routeid').val()),
```

Comment: You try put JS variable in PHP.
PHP executed firstly and don't know about JS. 
Then you should echoed firstly static php text, then change it by JS